# Typeahead not work in dialog edit of jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, typeahead

I tried to response the json from server like [the official demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/edit_add_delete/dialogs_edit_controls/index.html).

But the dropdown suggesion doesn't show up.

Could anyone tell me what I missed?
I only change the url from the demo code:

```java
{
    label: 'Ship Name2',
    name: 'ShipName2',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "text",
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (element) {
           $(element).attr("autocomplete","off").typeahead({ 
               appendTo : "body",
                source: function(query, proxy) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'mysite',
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {term: query},
                        success : proxy
                    });
                }
           });
        }
    }
}, {
    label: 'Ship Name',
    name: 'ShipName',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "text",
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (element) {
           $(element).attr("autocomplete","off").typeahead({ 
               appendTo : "body",
                source: function(query, proxy) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/autocompletepbs.php?callback=?&acelem=ShipName',
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {term: query},
                        success : proxy
                    });
                }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. My servlet return the same json which is exact the same as demo's.

Thanks!!

Edit 1: Is it possible that if I want to use typeahead in this demo, the response should not just be a json?

If I execute the [url](http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/autocompletepbs.php?callback=?&acelem=ShipName) in the demo, I would get the following javascript instead of json:

```java
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if(jQuery.ui) { 
            if(jQuery.ui.autocomplete){
                jQuery('ShipName').autocomplete({
                    "appendTo":"body",
                    "disabled":false,
                    "delay":300,
                    "minLength":1,
                    "source":function (request, response){
                        request.acelem = 'ShipName';
                        request.oper = 'autocmpl';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "autocompletep.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: request,
                            type: "GET",
                            error: function(res, status) {
                                alert(res.status+" : "+res.statusText+". Status: "+status);
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                }});
                jQuery('ShipName').autocomplete('widget').css('font-size','11px');
                jQuery('ShipName').autocomplete('widget').css('z-index','1000');
            } 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

The demo uses JSONP to obtain the data. If you are in local site you will need to remove calcback=? parameter.

The very basic testis is not to use ajax in typeahead, but array as data source. This way you will be sure that this work correct

Comment: Thx for your response.  But this still not work.  Is it possible that I should not just return a json?

Comment: The response can be any data type. You will need to read the docs of typeahead in order to configure it. You can use the link from the demo in order to be sure that there is response.